# Why static map does not retain the value in future methods?

Tags: rest, static, salesforce, apex, force.com

I have declared a map as a instance variable like this:

```
public class JSONParser_GET {
     public static Map<String, String> mapOfValues= new Map<String,String>();
 ...
```

Now, I have a future method where I am adding the values to this map:

```
@future(callout=true)
public static void getRequest(String type,String e,String authHeader){
    mapOfValues.put(type,lookupname);
    ...
```

But the values are not available when I try to access it in different method. Isn't that is what static is supposed to do?
As I am declaring it as static instance variable it should be globally available. I tried to use global keyword as well. But that also doesn't seems to work.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: `@future` spawns a new execution context and won't know where it came from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is what I did..
It seems future methods may execute in parallel due to which it is not possible to get the values from the response in one Map itself.
So I wrote a method before the getRequest and made it as future so that I can make only one instance of future handler.

`@future(callout==true)
    public class JSONParser_GET {
     public static Map<String, String> mapOfValues= new Map<String,String>();
        getRequest()
        getRequest()
        getRequest()
    }`

`public void getRequest{...}`

Answer (score 1):

I think, it's related to the [Future annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_future.htm). That means, the method getRequest() will be executed asynchronously, not with all usual methods.